# What is the correct way to provide Mathematica with a path to Python user scripts?

Tags: files-and-directories, python

What is the correct way to provide *Mathematica* with a path to Python user scripts?

Simply executing Python as a shell command, using something like

```
usefulOutput = Import["!python -c 'import mypkg; mypkg.use()'", "Text"];
```

fails, because *Mathematica* — like many IDEs and Python launchers — has no access to (or at least ignores) `PYTHONPATH` or any `sys.path.append` in 'shell_config.py'. I seem to be able to `Run` shell scripts without errors, but that's not what I'm looking fore here.

Does *Mathematica* provide a setting for extending `python.path` or is there a related directory setting in *Mathematica* that would result in my scripts being found?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath  possibly useful to you or others trying to help

Comment: look at os.environ to see what you are getting..

Comment: @george2079: Sorry, my example was terrible. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful..:

Prior to launching mathematica from a linux bash shell:

```
> NEWENV=WHATEVER
> export NEWENV
> mathematica
```

Now in the notebook:

```
 env = Import["!python -c 'import os;print os.environ'","Text"]
```

returns the whole environment as one big string. Now find the one I just made up..

```
Select[First@ImportString[StringTake[env,{2,-2}],"CSV",StringMatchQ[#,"*NEWENV*"]& ]
```

->

```
{ 'NEWENV': 'WHATEVER' }
```

Use the same approach to see if PYTHONPATH is even set.

You can also set an environment variable on the fly like this:

```
Import["!NEWENV=XX\nexport NEWENV\npython ... ","Text"]
```

Note that mathematica seems to launch a bourne or bash shell even if launched from some other shell.